# How to NOT mount dm-crypt device on Cinnamon startup

Tags: arch-linux, cinnamon, dm-crypt

Yeah this is counterclock-wise from anything I've found around.

In before anything: I'm running Arch Linux x64, Cinnamon 2.6.13, 4.1.6-1 kernel, no crypt hooks.

I've just made a test filesystem using dm-crypt/cryptsetup and it's all good. I didn't want to mount it on startup (because, well, it's supposed to require a password and being requested), however Cinnamon is doing this since I restarted it.

This is my crypttab and fstab. No inclusion. I did nothing about it.

```
root@darksol ~]# cat /etc/crypttab 
# crypttab: mappings for encrypted partitions
#
# Each mapped device will be created in /dev/mapper, so your /etc/fstab
# should use the /dev/mapper/<name> paths for encrypted devices.
#
# The Arch specific syntax has been deprecated, see crypttab(5) for the
# new supported syntax.
#
# NOTE: Do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up
#       beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf).

# <name>       <device>                                     <password>              <options>
# home         UUID=b8ad5c18-f445-495d-9095-c9ec4f9d2f37    /etc/mypassword1
# data1        /dev/sda3                                    /etc/mypassword2
# data2        /dev/sda5                                    /etc/cryptfs.key
# swap         /dev/sdx4                                    /dev/urandom            swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
# vol          /dev/sdb7                                    none
[root@darksol ~]# cat /etc/fstab 
# UUID=dbc726d2-05b9-416f-806d-30d464196a1c
/dev/mapper/linuxvg-arch_root_lv    /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# UUID=a63436fe-fa6b-480b-a94a-883c4b2a59e8
/dev/mapper/linuxvg-arch_usr_lv /usr        ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# UUID=d19aa437-d73f-4d61-a8f2-66126768c36a
/dev/mapper/linuxvg-opt_lv  /opt        ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# UUID=4bb50d46-c92b-4298-8aea-169c11fa3566
/dev/mapper/linuxvg-home_lv /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# UUID=bb02e9a7-4da3-41ff-acbe-e92b5d8f177a
/dev/sda2               none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

And so this is a peek at ~/.cinnamon (for my user of course) and glass.log.last

```
  [root@darksol .cinnamon]# cat glass.log.last 
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:08.840Z Cinnamon.AppSystem.get_default() started in 23 ms
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:16.790Z loading user theme: /home/meistache/.themes/Manjaro Maia Plasma 5/cinnamon/cinnamon.css
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:16.822Z added icon directory: /home/meistache/.themes/Manjaro Maia Plasma 5/cinnamon
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:16.922Z PlacesManager: Updating devices
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:17.000Z loaded at Tue Sep 22 2015 13:36:17 GMT-0300 (BRT)
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:17.523Z Loaded applet menu@cinnamon.org in 522 ms
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:17.529Z Role locked: windowlist
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:17.529Z Loaded applet window-list@cinnamon.org in 6 ms
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:42.544Z Loaded applet calendar@cinnamon.org in 25013 ms
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:42.549Z Loaded applet workspace-switcher@cinnamon.org in 5 ms
    info t=2015-09-22T16:36:42.555Z Loaded applet windows-quick-list@cinnamon.org in 6 ms
    [root@darksol .cinnamon]# pwd
/home/meistache/.cinnamon
    [root@darksol .cinnamon]#
```

It looks like it's something coded on Cinnamon engine for the PlacesManager method in which I may never ever be able to manage as user/superuser. I do need to report this as a feature request to Cinnamon devs but I'm wondering if anyone had this experience and got some workaround? Thanks in advance!